# Codeigniter- Function is always returning null

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

The getlocal is a database consult fuction but even when i insert data in my table called local the function can't return a different value from null

```
class denuncia_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

}
public function insertlocal($local){
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO local(estado,lng,lat) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($insertquery,$local);
}
public function getlocal($local){
    $queryteste = "SELECT * FROM local WHERE estado = ? AND lng = ? AND lat = ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($queryteste,$local);
    $row = $query->row_array();
    $id = $row['id'];
    return $id;

}
public function insertdenuncia($denuncia){
    $insertdenunciaquery = "INSERT INTO denuncias(descricao,data,forma,genero,preconceito,idade,id_local) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($insertdenunciaquery,$denuncia);

}
```

file denuncia_controller

```
        $local = array($estado,$lng,$lat);
        $denuncia = array($descricao,$data,$agressao,$gender,$preconceito,$age);
        $this->denuncia_model->insertlocal($local);
        $id = $this->denuncia_model->getlocal($local);
        array_push($denuncia,$id);
        $this->denuncia_model->insertdenuncia($denuncia,$local);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class denuncia_model extends CI_Model {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

}
public function insertlocal($local){
    $insertquery = "INSERT INTO local(estado,lng,lat) VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $this->db->query($insertquery,$local);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}
```

Comment: Use return $this->db->insert_id(); when inserting used that return integer value

Comment: Thanks ! you solved my question.(And sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 0):

you should use return statement with insert_id() in the end of the function

```
return $this->db->insert_id();
```